# How can I "Parse" array returned by ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 spans on my page that contain numbers. On click of a button I would like to retrieve an ajax response, and if the response is valid (it should be an array of 3 elements) I would like to update the numbers in these spans. Could you please recommend a solution via jQuery?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON(url, function(resp)
{
  var list = resp.list;
  if(!list)
  {
    throw new Exception("list is not set");
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
  {
    $('#span' + (i + 1)).text(list[i]);
  }
});
```

if the spans have ids span1, span2, and span3.  See [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for more information.  Note that you can add error handling by using `$.ajax` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Quick question: what should a resp string look like?

Comment: By the time it gets to your callback, it's no longer a string.  However, before jQuery parses it, it will look like `{"list": ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement this by usig jQuery.getJson(url,callback(data,textStatus)) .

for example :

$.getJSON(url, function(data,textStatus){
  var spanValues = data.list;
  $('#span_Id').text(spanValues [i]);
...

});

Comment: It's trivial question ,and the answer from Mattew Flaschen is same but better one.